# How can I see how many times I have used fopen on a file?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am working on a linux system.  I have a multi-threaded application that has `n` file handles open on a single file `f`.  How can I see during run-time how many file handles in my process refer to `n`?

Comment: Usually, you'd just count them yourself. It's your code, after all. But why would you need this?

Comment: Considering I gave you no information on my project, you can assume that my question may be in regards to any possible software project.  Can you not imagine a single case out of the infinite possibilities of software in which it may be useful to know how many times a file is opened?

Comment: I can imagine millions of cases in which it's useful, and also millions of cases in which you'd just count. Computers rarely suffer from amnesia, it's easy to remember what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the symbolic links in `/proc/self/fd/` and see if there are multiple descriptors pointing to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

you can run **`lsof -p pid of your process`** to verify opened file from your process

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be as simple as writing a function

you could make a simple class if you would want, then yo could increment on open and decrement on close and handle other stuff.

```
long myopen(char* filenmae)
{
    static long count = 0;

    // open file
    // mutex
    count++;  
    // mutex

    return count;
}
```