# Can I know how many processes are opening a same file in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Is there a 'reference count' on a file that maintains how many processes are opening a file in C/C++? Or is there any alternative approach to do so? I've looked at `fstat` but it seems that it doesn't provide such information.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how it is possible to open a file by more than one handle / process?

Comment: @nada You just call `open` on it.

Comment: Didn't know this was possible :O

Comment: A single process can open the same file multiple times; multiple processes can open the same file too.  A process can duplicate a file descriptor easily.  Processes fork, which duplicates the file descriptors, and may or may not close the file after forking.  There isn't an easy way to get the number you're looking for.  It isn't even particularly clear what number you _are_ looking for.  It might be the number of open file descriptors, or the number of open file descriptions (that's different) or the number of processes with at least one open file descriptor, or description, or …

Comment: If you don't need it programmatically just use `lsof`.

Comment: Or `fuser` if `lsof` seems like overkill ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler We can assume no `fork` and one process will open only one time. Actually I just want to use a file to keep track of a group of processes who is still alive, so every process will open that file when it start.

Comment: Candidate originals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803498/how-can-i-see-how-many-times-i-have-used-fopen-on-a-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546155/determine-how-many-times-file-is-mapped-into-memory). Of course, the information is stale immediately upon acquisition, as other processes can open or close a file at any moment.

Comment: You are going to need to use some Linux API (if one exists).  Both the C and C++ (separate languages), don't have standard functionality to query file attributes.

Comment: File status is not intended for IPC (Inter-Process Communication). And IPC is what you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/404622/8074683.

Comment: May I ask what is your purpose for accessing it?